# Mafia-type game which a secret message is communicated

Tags: identify-this-game, party

During a recent visit to Europe, I saw some students playing a game that looked something like Mafia that played roughly like this (linguistic difficulties prevented me from any further understanding):  a group of 5-7 people were having essentially a normal conversation, and there were 2-3 "spies" who were trying to communicate some sort of message between each other, such as a pair of rhyming words or the beginning and end of a phrase.  The spies did not know each other's identities and were trying not to be "caught" by the other players, so the idea was that they had to weave these phrases into the conversation naturally.  There were other players with their own objectives as well, but I couldn't follow what they were.

Does this kind of game ring any bells with anyone?  Wikipedia is not returning anything useful.

Answer (score 5):

Not a perfect fit, but **it sounds a bit like [Speakeasy](http://thegamehaschanged.net/speakeasy/)**, a party game in which you use a secret password to identify your teammates and try to deduce as much as you can about the other side, including their passwords and roles etc.

There are two sides (Feds and Mob) which are equally balanced and the game includes roles and "powers" which mix things up a lot.

Comment: That's a very interesting-looking game!  Thanks for the link.